не получается отправить данные на серверный компонент
на клиенте
 function handleSubmit(e: any, email: string, password: string) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("try to server push");
    const data = {email, password};
    fetch('/api/sendlogin', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
      });
  }

на сервере
    import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';


export default async function sendLogin(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    console.log("not post");// в консоли вот это появляется. т.е. маршрут работает. как 
                            //  так, почему он считает, что метод не POST?
    return;
  }

  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    // Проверяем, чтобы email и password были отправлены
    if (!email || !password) {
      console.log("not email or password");
      return;
    }

    console.log("Req email: " + email);

    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Данные успешно добавлены в базу данных' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Ошибка при выполнении запроса к базе данных:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Ошибка сервера' });
  }
};

